# Delay between windows form opening

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screen, multiple-monitors

I am working on windows form application in dual monitor scenario in which 2 forms open on one screen and other 3 forms open on secondary screen.

Let me explain you real time scenario-

```
screen 1         Screen 2               Case
Form1             desktop                1
Form2             form 3                 2  delay is not visible because earlier screen was desktop only
Form2            desktop                 3  When i open form 4 it gives delay of few ms and show desktop
Form2             Form4                  4  Now After delay it opens form 4
```

Now my question is what can be the reason's of delay

- Any hardware issue
- Any other process which is holding some time.
- Is there any way by which i can check delay reason.
- Else reason which i don't know.

As this question cover's whole project, Its not possible to provide any code snippet. Search engine results are also not helping.

Comment: Do you use any special code to make it open on different monitors? Can you reproduce this on blank forms on a plain winforms application? If it opens fast, then it is your code. Otherwise, let us know how you open your forms.

Comment: What's the difference between Forms3 and 4? I suspect the time to load/render/display them by themselves is already different. Have you tried opening all of the forms in 1 screen?

Comment: @MarkMenchavez not yet will try ..

Answer (score 1):

When you have forms that seems slow to load and show, try to reduce the number of tasks it needs to do on Form Load.  Try to move some of them in Form Activate when appropriate.  Do not open and close forms unnecessarily, try to hide already load forms and just show them again when needed.  You can also try using a background worker component to do the heavy processing needed.  This way, the form is already displayed while a background task is running.